# MPAndroidChart - How to change the color of PieChart center Background?

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

Im trying to use the [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library to develop a circular chart. But only Pie chart is available. So i tried giving two xvalue coordinates, with one color similar to background. So i got something similar to circular chart. But i'm not able to change the background color and font color of center text inside the pie chart?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible solutions:

Retrieve the `Paint` object used by the chart to draw the "center-hole" and modify it the way you want

```
Paint p1 = mChart.getPaint(Chart.PAINT_HOLE);
p1.setColor(...);

Paint p2 = mChart.getPaint(Chart.PAINT_CENTER_TEXT);
p2.setColor(...);
```

Or use this, if you only display one value anyway: [**CircleDisplay**](https://github.com/PhilJay/CircleDisplay)

Comment: Circle display seems to be a good option. I was checking out android charts earlier, so i didnt see this earlier. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: `mChart.getPaint(Chart.PAINT_HOLE)` would always return `null`. If fact `getPaint` returns only null values. Any ideas why?

Comment: The answer provided by MRK is the good way to update this color. Don't update the paint if the library provides a way to update the colors.

Answer (score 12):

To set center color:

```
mChart.setDrawHoleEnabled(true);
mChart.setHoleColor(...);
```

To set center text

```
mChart.setDrawCenterText(true);
mChart.setCenterText(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pieChart.setHoleColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Color1));
```

Comment: Add some explanation, please.