# Is it possible to draw the line chart value vertically via Android use MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, linechart

Do you have any idea to set background color for x-axis ?
I have a problem when i customized with x-axis.

I want to do this.

[set background color for x-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsQuf.png)

Is it possible?

Thx in advance

[Edit]

```
  public class TargetZoneLineChart extends LineChart{

    protected Paint mYAxisSafeZonePaint;
    private List<TargetZone> mTargetZones;

    @Override
    protected void init() {
      super.init();
      mYAxisSafeZonePaint = new Paint();
      mYAxisSafeZonePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
      mTargetZones = new ArrayList<>();
    }

   @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    for (TargetZone targetZone : mTargetZones) {
        // prepare coordinates
        float[] pts = new float[4];
        pts[1] = targetZone.lowerLimit;
        pts[3] = targetZone.upperLimit;
        mLeftAxisTransformer.pointValuesToPixel(pts);

        // draw
        mYAxisSafeZonePaint.setColor(targetZone.color);
        canvas.drawRect(mViewPortHandler.contentLeft(), pts[1], mViewPortHandler.contentRight(),
                pts[3], mYAxisSafeZonePaint);
    }
    super.onDraw(canvas);
   }

    public void addTargetZone(TargetZone targetZone){
         mTargetZones.add(targetZone);
     }

    public List<TargetZone> getTargetZones(){
         return mTargetZones;
     }    

    public static class TargetZone {
    public final int color;
    public final float lowerLimit;
    public final float upperLimit;

    public TargetZone(int color, float lowerLimit, float upperLimit) {
        this.color = color;
        this.lowerLimit = lowerLimit;
        this.upperLimit = upperLimit;
    }
}
```

it only yAxis , if I want to be xAxis , what do I do ?

Comment: which library is used to display the pi chart?

Comment: Hope this may help you?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25927977/mpandroidchart-how-to-change-the-color-of-piechart-center-background

Comment: @ Rahul Kushwaha : MPAndroidChart lineChart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had used this library for showing  diagram of days of a week . You can  use and customised for your requirement. As per your requirement, I had done same type of task. Please see below method and use it. Hope this may help you.If any questions please comment.

private fun setDayBarchart(){

```
    val yVals1 = ArrayList<BarEntry>()
    yVals1.add(BarEntry(0f, 6f))
    yVals1.add(BarEntry(1f, 1f))
    yVals1.add(BarEntry(2f, 2f))
    yVals1.add(BarEntry(3f, 3f))
    yVals1.add(BarEntry(4f, 5f))
    yVals1.add(BarEntry(5f, 4f))
    yVals1.add(BarEntry(6f, 7f))

    val set1: BarDataSet
    set1 = BarDataSet(yVals1, "")
    set1.setColors(ColorTemplate.rgb("439CFF"))
    val dataSets = ArrayList<IBarDataSet>()
    dataSets.add(set1)

    val data = BarData(dataSets)
    data.setValueTextSize(7f)
    data.barWidth = 0.5f

    val formatter = object : ValueFormatter() {
        // the labels that should be drawn on the XAxis
        val quarter = arrayOf("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat")

        override fun getAxisLabel(value: Float, axis: AxisBase?): String {
            return quarter[value.toInt()]
        }
    }

    val xAxis = root.barChart.xAxis
    xAxis.granularity=1f // minimum axis-step (interval) is 1
    xAxis.valueFormatter=formatter
    xAxis.position=XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM
    xAxis.textSize=10f
    xAxis.textColor=Color.BLACK
    xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false)
    root.barChart.setTouchEnabled(false)
    root.barChart.data=data
    root.barChart.animateXY(2000, 2000)
    root.barChart.setFitBars(true)
    root.barChart.getDescription().setText(" ")
}
```

Comment: :Thanks, but I am not only show bar chart but line chart , in fact , according to my photo, x is date , it's will be 12/15 , 12/16 , 12/17, some special day will need to change x axis background. and y asis will be float value , for example : 34.5 ,33.5...

Comment: @林姿妤 you can change in line chart also read the documetation .You can find the details as your requirement.You can change X axis backgroound also.

Comment: read the documentation this https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/main/java/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/CombinedChartActivity.java

Comment: :I have a idea . maybe not use CombinedChart , if I can let specially day , for example,12/15 , make xAxis line is thicker.

Comment: @林姿妤 i think there is no options to make any particular line(12/15) thikcker and Colored.  It will colored or change any item then whole xaxis item will be affected.Try another library to get your desired result.

Comment: @林姿妤 Sorry, Actually I found some solutions in this link .Please  study the code and implement as your requirement.https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/tree/master/MPChartExample/src/main/java/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample                        https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/main/java/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/BarChartActivityMultiDataset.java

Comment: @林姿妤  try both link study it .if any problem i will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Combined-Chart (bar- and linechart in this case)** which is available in MPAndroidChart.

You can find the use in the following library:
[MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/main/java/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/CombinedChartActivity.java)

Comment: Thanks ,I know Combined-Chart , in fact , https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/3406 has show Combined-Chart, but no any example.  I know draw different background color base on yalis value , but xalis value , i really do't kno.

Comment: For demo, you can follow below link
https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/main/java/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/CombinedChartActivity.java